# Question about tangent space of a level set of function.

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry

In McDuff and Salamon's book p343, they claimed:

> The hypersurface $\Sigma$ is of dimension $2n−2$ and the tangent space at $p$ is
>
> $T_p\Sigma= \{ v ∈ T_pM | dG(p)v = dH(p)v = 0\}.$

Here, M is a manifold, $G$ and $H$ are two function on M (H is a Hamiltonian function), $G(p_0) = 0, {G, H}(p_0)  = 0 $, $\Sigma =H^{-1}(0)\cap G^{-1}(0)$.

Since we do not know if $0$ is a regular value of $G$ or $H$, we do not know if $H^{-1}(0)$ and $G^{-1}(0)$ are regular submanifolds (or what we call embedded submanifolds), so why $T_pH=\{v ∈ T_pM |  dH(p)v \neq 0\}$?

In this book they mentioned that every level set of a Hamiltonian function is an invariant submanifold, I am not sure if they meant a regular submanifold or an immersed one? If they are regular  submanifold, it seems our question has been solved, but what if it is an immersed submanifold?

Comment: A regular value can be taken as $0$ without loss of generality. Indeed, if $c$ is a regular value of $H$, then $0$ is a regular value of $H'$, with $H'(x)=H(x)-c$.

Comment: @Asier López-Gordón You are right, but they do not say it, that is the point.

Comment: Just checking: Is $H$ a Hamiltonian for a circle action?

Comment: @Andrew D. Hwang Yes, we assume the Hamiltonian vector field of $H$, $X_H$ has periodic, but then? Could you please say more?